# Node - Save m3u8 stream as mp3 file

Tags: javascript, node.js, m3u8

I have been looking around for a few hours to figure out how I can convert a m3u8 stream into a local mp3 file.

I can't seem to find a module to handle this, so I were just wondering if anyone here have experience with doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: I made a module that does this a while back: https://github.com/fent/node-m3u8stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M3U8 is just a XML file that contains a playlist.

You could use an XML parsing library like [XML2JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) to read and parse the file contents and then use the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library to download those files with node.

Comment: There's various node libraries out there to download the .TS chunks of a playlist (more often than not one track is split up onto 15-20 ts chunks) however combining them requires me to store them locally and then combine them using ffmpeg. I were just wondering if there's an module I've missed that does this for you.